# Nested business access token issue (facebook)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm very new to the graph api, now a company hired me to make software involving analyzing their functionality.

So I have user id: eg123
they have user/buisness id:eg456

I have permissions only to manage one of their pages, which is fine, but now how do I get the data from a page I have access to from my side, as they refuse to learn how to generate access tokens, so they just gave me basic access to one of their pages data? Specifically insights

now when I try

[getting pages my user owns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woxDO.png)

It gives me access to pages that I own,
but now replace despite me having being granted access, when I replace my id with their's

It doesn't only give me access to pages I may see, but gives

[the issue when I replace the my ID with their's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Sgg.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"so they just gave me basic access to one of their pages data"_ - meaning what, exactly?